# Adding score to a quizz with javascript

Tags: javascript

Got this quizz that Im using and i wondering if there is someone that may help me with introducing a score displaying

Like, your score is : x/y

Tried to watch some javasc tutorials but got stucks as damn on numbers. Thank u !!

If there is need for any further details, im always online :d

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/YB2KB/)

```js
function clearAnswers(){
  $("img").each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    
  })
}

function markIncorrect(el){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'http://www.littletherese.com/x.jpg';
  el.append(img);
}

function markCorrect(el){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'http://www.littletherese.com/tick.jpg';
  el.append(img);
}

$("form").on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  clearAnswers();

  $questions = $(".question");
  $questions.each(function(){
    var answer = $(this).find("input:checked"),
        key = answer.attr("name"),
        val = answer.attr("value");

    if(answer.length === 0){
      markIncorrect($(this).find("p"));
    } else if (answers[key] !== val){
      markIncorrect($(this).find("p"));
    } else {
      markCorrect(answer.parent());
    }
  });
});

var answers = {
  "one": "a",
  "two": "b"
}
```

```css
label{ display: block; }
input[type=submit]{ margin-top: 15px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="question">
        <p><strong>Q1</strong>: Mary is English. She was born in London</p>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="one" value="a">Mary was born in England</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="one" value="b">Mary, who is English, was born in London</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="one" value="c">English Mary was born in London</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="one" value="d">London Mary is English born</label>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
        <p><strong>Q2</strong>: Mary is English. She was born in London</p>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="two" value="a">Mary was born in England</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="two" value="b">Mary, who is English, was born in London</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="two" value="c">English Mary was born in London</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="two" value="d">London Mary is English born</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS functions are objects, you can add any property to it like:

```
function markCorrect(el){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'http://www.littletherese.com/tick.jpg';
  el.append(img);
}

markCorrect.calls = 0;
```

Of course you have to increment that value, lets do it when `markCorrect` is called:

```
function markCorrect(el){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'http://www.littletherese.com/tick.jpg';
  el.append(img);
  markCorrect.calls++;
}
```

After `$questions.each` loop you / your code will know how many times each method has been executed

```
console.log(markCorrect.calls, markIncorrect.calls)
```

Only one step left with adding those information to HTML instead to the console

The side note - please try to move validation to backend side instead of frontend, as everyone could see proper answers.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/angelsmall13/7nezcf92/3/
Added the functions you were talking about and the html part, yet, now running it displays 404 error :-?

Comment: I suggest something like https://jsfiddle.net/gcto189r/

Comment: It is indeed what i was looking for. And now saw where i was mistaking. Thank for your help ! <3

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gf5x9ewv/ I ve updated it and it works amazing.
One more question, tho. It has a bug. As i press check multiple times, the score goes up too. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You have to clear previous calculations, clearAnswers looks like proper place for it - 
`
function clearAnswers() {
  $("img").each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  markCorrect.calls = 0;
  markIncorrect.calls = 0;
}
`